# Beamer & XeLaTeX math font resets to sans serif

Tags: beamer, xetex, math-fonts, lmodern

I need to compile a beamer slideshow with xelatex. I set "Latin Modern Math" as my math font but it was reset to sans serif. Looks awful.

If I set \documentclass as article, everything works.

Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures={TeX}}
\setmainfont{CMU Serif}
\setsansfont{CMU Sans Serif}
\setmonofont{CMU Typewriter Text}  
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
$$
  \sin \frac{\pi}{4} = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}
$$
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

It compiles into pdf file looking like that:[image]

I run Debian stretch, all tex packages are from repos. texlive version:

```
 $ dpkg -s texlive
Package: texlive
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: tex
Installed-Size: 68
Maintainer: Debian TeX Maintainers 
Architecture: all
Multi-Arch: foreign
Source: texlive-base
Version: 2016.20161008-1
Depends: texlive-latex-base (>= 2016), texlive-latex-recommended (>= 2016), texlive-fonts-recommended (>= 2016)
Description: TeX Live: A decent selection of the TeX Live packages
 The TeX Live software distribution offers a complete TeX system. It
 encompasses programs for typesetting, previewing and printing of TeX
 documents in many different languages, and a large collection of TeX macros
 and font libraries. . This metapackage provides a decent selection of the
 TeX Live packages which should suffice for the most common tasks. . The
 distribution also includes extensive general documentation about TeX, as
 well as the documentation accompanying the included software packages.
Homepage: http://www.tug.org/texlive/
```

xelatex.log is pasted there: http://pastebin.com/MM1h2EU2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The font set up in `beamer` is meant to be usable 'as is' but doesn't 'play nicely' with loading other font set ups. For those, you want to retain full control with

```
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
```